# assign string returned from remote url to variable

Tags: java, android

I am trying to assign a string from a remote URL to a variable. When I check that variable after running the remote URL code it is empty. 
first I declared empty string then fetched string from URL and try to assign it to the variable. the string is fetched but not assigned to the variable.

below is code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static String channel_uri = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new DownloadWebPageTask().execute();

    if(channel_uri.isEmpty()){
        Log.i("channel_text", "Empty");
    }
}

private static class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://yeshuaatv.com/channel/streamingurl/adaptive.txt")
                .build();
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful())
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
            channel_uri = response.body().string();
            return channel_uri;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //tvdata.setText(channel);
        // you will get data in url string
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Try using volley it has more cleaner interface that is understandable.

Comment: @Sree Hi, Tried volley. but same thing happened....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `execute()` method starts the Task in a new Thread and does this asynchronously. That means while the HTTP Request is happening, your code from `onCreate` keeps running and your `if` check happens before the request finished.

To work around this, you have to wait for the request to finish and execute your code there. To accomplish this with `AsyncTask` you can override `onPostExecute` which gets run on the UI Thread after the Task has finished.

Your code would look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String channel_uri) {
    if(channel_uri.isEmpty()){
        Log.i("channel_text", "Empty");
    }
}
```

This also should remove the usage of a class member for channel_uri. Because that gets passed into `onPostExecute`

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. I am new on android. I understand it, but problem is I need to first fetch the remote url, then execute other code. Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

'onCreate' and 'doInBackground' are running in different threads. So this code

```
 if(channel_uri.isEmpty()){
    Log.i("channel_text", "Empty");
}
```

executes before you receive the response in AsyncTask.

That is why it is called a AsyncTask. You need to log the channel_uri in doInBackground when you receive the response.